# Various kinds of whitespace in LaTeX

Tags: spacing

Is it true that it is customary to use `' '` for the distance between words and `\;` for the distance between symbols like `.` `,` `:` `;` `?` `_` `-` `(` `{` `[` and the next word?

Comment: Are you asking it is it normal to use a `space` between words and those chars? Not really, though some languages, like French, have certain rules.

Comment: The width of ; and ?  or / is very different.

Comment: It depends on your language, I suppose. French in particular uses (small) whitespace before most punctuation (Babel does it automatically, if memory serves) while most other languages do not.

Comment: @daleif I say ''Is it normal to use `\;` between those characters and the next word?"

Comment: @Uwe How are they different?

Comment: @Ingmar How about English? And I'm not talking about the distance between punctuation and the previous word, But I'm talking about the distance between it and the next word

Comment: @Emad: Use single spacing (i.e. one normal space after your comma, (semi)colon, period, etc.) and leave the rest to your document class.

Comment: In some, but not all, English-language typographic traditions, it is customary to add a bit of whitespace *between sentences*. There are 3 sentence-ending punctuation marks in English: `.`, `?`, and `!`. Do note that (a) `,` `;`, and `:` do *not* end (grammatically recognizable) sentences and (b) `.` ("period", "full stop") is often used to denote an abbreviation -- say, "Mr. Smith and Ms. Jones" -- *within* a sentence and hence does not necessarily indicate the *end* of a sentence. TeX can be told to ignore this  typographic tradition by issuing the instruction `\frenchspacing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,  do not use `\;` . (Until the very latest release `\;` was a math-mode-only command and would give an error in text mode.)

Just use a normal space as in

```
Some text. The next sentence: a clause after a colon.
```

The space after the punctuation (and especially in French styles) the space before the punctuation will be controlled by document level settings, not by adding markup at every punctuation character.

Here is the above text set three ways

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

Some text. The next sentence: a clause after a colon.

{\frenchspacing
Some text. The next sentence: a clause after a colon.

}


\foreignlanguage{french}{Some text. The next sentence: a clause after a colon.}

\end{document}
```

By default space after `:` is extended a bit and space after `.` is extended more.

In `\frenchspacing` space after `:` and `.` is a normal word space.

In the french settings from `babel`  space is inserted before punctuation such as `:` to match the usual style in French.